# How do I retrieve a specific instance in the constructor, when there are multiple instances

Tags: structuremap, structuremap4

I'm using structuremap 4.5.1.  I have two instances of an interface, and I need to know how to retrieve a specific one in my constructor.  So in this case, I have one class that requires one of the instances of my interface, then I have a different class that requires the second instance of my interface, but not the first instance.  Since interfaces are commonly used to be implemented in multiple classes, I feel like this *has* to be a common scenario, but I can't understand how to do it.

I found a concept called "Named Instances" in the documentation, so I would have thought that was the solution, but it doesn't work.

Here is my registry:

```
    For<IFileWatcher>().Add<Watcher>().Named("fileWatcher");
    For<IFileWatcher>().Add<InboundWatcher>().Named("inboundWatcher");

    For<IFileWatcher>().Use<Watcher>();
```

And here is my constructor, that doesn't work (when I say it doesn't work, I mean structuremap only supplies the default instance, even though I named the constructor parameter the same as in my registry):

```
private readonly IFileWatcher _fileWatcher;

public InboundWatcherController(IFileWatcher inboundWatcher) //<-- notice the name is the same as in my registry
{
    _watcher = inboundWatcher; //<-- this is set to an instance of "Watcher", instead of "InboundWatcher" even though the name of the parameter is "inboundWatcher"
}
```

So, how do I get an instance of "InboundWatcher" instead of "Watcher" in my constructor?  Do I have to use the container?  That seems really backwards to have to bring in the container just so I can get a specific instance of a class.